# Vue js and Python flask API architecture

Tags: python, vue.js, security, authentication, flask-restful

I am new into vue and flask api planning to build a blog using Vue js frontend and flask api to manipulate date.

I am having some architectural question. In flask api I can create token auth based on use login and shared it Vue for access. But in flask api I am manipulating data say delete a blog post, edit a post etc. So if the end point get exposed say http://127.0.0.1:5000/deletePost<post_id> normal user can hit the api with any post id and delete it from database. How do I stop that ? I want to authenticate the user and secure the data manipulation by admin role only. Also I want to use flask-login current user to keep track of the session and show the related post and content.

Any suggested architecture for it ?

I am not sure if this is a valid question or not. I am just trying to understand the architecture here. Suppose I have a user collection in mongo DB. So when user login with valid user name and password flask will create access token which I will pass to Vue and store in local storage. Now there is a route say delete post with post ID where I am removeing the post from database. Now if the delete api got exposed, a valid login user can fire this delete api with any post id (Note I am using post id in vue template as identifier) with their access token. How do it secure it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using flask-login you can create your own User Model.
Simply inherit from UserMixin & db.Model. There you can store wether the user is an admin.

Something like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """User account model."""

    __tablename__ = 'flasklogin-users'
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = db.Column(
        db.String(100),
        nullable=False,
        unique=False
    )
    email = db.Column(
        db.String(40),
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    password = db.Column(
        db.String(200),
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    is_admin = db.Column(
        db.Boolean(),
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
        default=False
    )
```

You then use your that class to create new Users, add them to the session on login & call login_user with an instance of that class. current_user should then give you access to this user and you can simple check for is_admin. And if anyone that is not an admin you simply return a Response with and errorstatus.

If you plan on having more than 2 Roles you could use a String Column instead an then check for that role.

If this is something that happens often you could create a decorator that checks if the user is an admin & simply put it in front of your rows.

Edit:
What i would do is something like this:

```
@app.route('/deletepost/<post_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_post():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user.is_admin:        
        return Response(status=500)
```

if that happens more often what you could to is abstract that logic out into an decorator like this:

```
def is_admin(fn):
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user.is_admin:        
            return Response(status=500)
        return fn(*args,**kwargs)
```

you can than use that like this:

```
@app.route('/deletepost/<post_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
@is_admin
def delete_post():
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already created this model for mongo DB and I can use login_user to track the session. But I want to secure the database operation. like before ant db request in flask-api it will validate the admin user id and password. so if the general user want to access api using access token cant manupulate the database. Hope I calrified my point.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean exactly. You want to secure the api endpoint without any databse request? Maybe you can share some code to clarify what you mean.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for your help

Comment: Updated it again ;) Shows you how to use a decorator for this. That way you can abstract out the logic and jsut chain those decorators.

Comment: @SubhananGanguli Would you mark my answer as accepted if this works? :)